# how many characters should i limit a thread body to?

Tags: doctrine

im using doctrine and need to specify the length of a thread body (datatype: blob).

i wonder how many characters i should limit the user to type for a thread body?

what is normal?

thanks!

Comment: Surely this is dependant on your application and not a general thought?

Comment: Did you mean: `the length of the post body (type: clob)?` If you want to allow your users to write books in one post, set no limit at all. Is round 1024 enough for you? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BLOB datatype is simply a binary large object, I am not sure if your question relates to the size or length of what they *should* type, or *should be able to type.*